# Keyboard typing random letters

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I am running Windows 10 build 18945 and random applications (most of them) are getting typed in random letters. I have found many things saying check your input language but i only have one that is English (US).

And the random letter a key will type is not always the same. I can hold down 'a' for instance and it'll type a series of numbers and letters. So it is not consistent

Example, copy and pasted holding down 'a'

```
d9wmw9dmdkdjw9wmwjw9woekwoiwmwekwnd
```

One of the only applications that correctly recognizes the input is Firefox

Pretty sure it isn't a hardware issue, because it is not in all applications.

This is an integrated keyboard in the Lenovo ThinkPad T430s

It also seems to be intermittent

**EDIT** If i remember right, this started around disabling credential and device guard (I can't use any emulator/virtualization with them on because the virtualization is then exclsuively used by Hyper-V, and i needed to run Intel HAXM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this exact problem. I work IT and found it rather annoying after performing a ton of troubleshooting steps from changing keyboards to trying to configure Windows settings. It was also happening on both my laptops.

I then came across an article from another IT person who said it was his Kaspersky/Zone Alarm anti-keylogger. Which is a program I don't use, though I do use Sophos which has a similar function. He was able to update Zone Alarm and it worked. I uninstalled Sophos and watched as the list of components were removed. As soon as the keylogger was removed it started to work again. Check your anti-virus! I will be reaching out to Sophos for an answer.

Comment: Yeah it seems to have been sophos key encryption crap. Upvoted and accepted